# OpenGL maintain object shape on window resize

Tags: c++, opengl, orthographic

I have a square and I'm trying to make it stay a square when the window is resized, instead of stretching with the window. I have some code which I thought would work but when I resize the window the square shrinks and disappears. It doesn't come back when I return the window to it's original size. Can someone tell me what I've done wrong and how to fix it?

```
void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5);
    glVertex2f(-0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex2f(0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex2f(0.5, -0.5);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
    return;
}

void reshape(int w, int h) {
    const float aspectRatio = ((float)w) / h;
    float xSpan = 1;
    float ySpan = 1;

    if (aspectRatio > 1) {
        xSpan *= aspectRatio;
    }
    else {
        ySpan *= aspectRatio;
    }

    gluOrtho2D(-1*xSpan, xSpan, -1*ySpan, ySpan);
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutCreateWindow("simple");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Why do You call `gluOrtho2D` in reshape function? It should rather contain code that will reset the projection matrix to identity... Call `gluOrtho2D` in display function instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions [`gluOrtho2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluOrtho2D.xml) and [`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml) multiply the current matrix by the new orthographic projection matrix.
This causes that if the `reshape` is called a 2nd time, the matrix which was set by `gluOrtho2D` before, is multiplied by the new one and you get consecutive changes.

You have to "reset" the matrix (init the identiy matrix) on the matrix stack by [`glLoadIdentity`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLoadIdentity.xml). Further you should choose the projection matrix stack by [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml):

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D(-1*xSpan, xSpan, -1*ySpan, ySpan);
```

The setup of the viewport [`glViewport`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glViewport.xml) is correct and you also consider the aspect ratio correctly (in `gluOrtho2D`). But there is an issue if the aspect ratio is less than 1.0. It should be `ySpan /= aspectRatio;`

I recommend to do the setting of the viewport and the projection matrix in the `display` function and just to set a notification flag in the `reshape` function. Note, the viewport and the projection matrix should be changed as rare as possible.

```
bool vp_valid = true;
int  width, height;

void reshape(int w, int h) {
    vp_valid = false;
    width = w;
    height = h;
}

void display(void)
{
    if (!vp_valid)
    {
      const float aspectRatio = (float)width / height;
      float sx = aspectRatio > 1.0f ? aspectRatio : 1.0f;
      float sy = aspectRatio > 1.0f ? 1.0f : 1.0f/aspectRatio;

      glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
      glLoadIdentity();
      gluOrtho2D(-sx, sx, -sy, sy);

      glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    .....
}
```